# How to find the diffrence between two directory using byondcompare or kdiff exe

Tags: mercurial

i have a local and remote repository and have to find the difference between them by using byond compare or kdiff.
i made changes in hgrc as well mercurial.ini file as below.

[extensions]
hgext.extdiff=

[extdiff]
cmd.bc3diff = C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 3\BCompare.exe
opts.bc3diff = -f '+next' '+execute "DirDiff ".argv(0)." ".argv(1)'

and tried in command prompt hg bc3diff source directory remote directory

but got abort source directory not under root......

please help me how could i solve above problem.

thanks,

Comment: Your `Beyond Compare` configuration doesn't look right.  See http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs for how to set it up to work with Mercurial.

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial operates on local repositories, and the `diff` and `extdiff` commands compare two different revisions in the same local repository (or the local working dir).  The only built-in commands that compare local revisions to remote are `incoming` and `outgoing` (with optional --patch), but they don't launch external viewers.

You can use the [rdiff extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RdiffExtension) to compare a local revision to a remote repo revision, but it doesn't seem to launch external tools.

The right/normal way to do this is to clone/pull both repos into one new clone and do local v. local comparisons there.

Comment: i tried with rdiffextension but got no output. i adding following lines:in .hgrc to enable the extension 
[extensions]
rdiff=/path/to/rdiff.py

actually,i have to find the difference between two latest revision in remote directory or doing hg clone in local direcoty and find the difference files and changes accordingly in workdirectory.

Comment: Cloning them locally is the right way to do it.  If, however, they're adjacent revisions in history and the two-latest at that you can do `hg incoming -p --newest-first --limit 1 URL-OF-REMOTE`.  That'll be a standard diff not your beyond-compare diff, but a good gui merge tool will display those w/ a few gaps too.